# Modify and return ModelAttribute object if validation fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have simple entity ...

```
@Entity
public class WatchedDirectory {
    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotBlank(message="Filesystem path CANNOT be empty")
    String filesystemPath;
}
```

... and GET endpoint for creating one ...

```
    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String add(@ModelAttribute WatchedDirectory watchedDirectory) {
        return "mng-dir-add";
    }
```

... that shows form made in Thymeleaf, with error validation and all. Once you hit sumbmit button data goes into POST endpoint ...

```
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addExecute(@Valid @ModelAttribute WatchedDirectory watchedDirectory, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirect, Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            // here I want to iterate through
            // errors and clean erroneous fields
            return "mng-dir-add";
        }
        watchedDirectory = fs.persistDirectory(watchedDirectory);
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("added", watchedDirectory);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }
```

... and everything is nice and dandy. When data is valid it get persisted and redirect to list is issued (POST/Redirect/GET). When data is invalid thymeleaf's error fields are populated and I list error messages below appropriate fields.

The only thing I want to change, but I can't figure out how to, is to clear some data from model.

Things I tried so far: modifying `@ModelAttribute` parameter, setting attributes in `Model`, setting attributes in `RedirectAttributes`. Every time I get the very same data user provided without any changes in output form, for some reason I can't change a thing. I tried also redirecting to GET method but it seems it clears slate clean, which I don't want.

If someone is interested this is how form in thymeleaf looks:

```
        <form id="content" action="#" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${watchedDirectory}" method="post" class="was-validated">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback has-error">
                <label for="filesystemPath">Filesystem path:</label>
                <input th:field="*{filesystemPath}" type="text" id="filesystemPath" name="filesystemPath" class="form-control" placeholder="~/" required />
                <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('filesystemPath')}" th:errors="*{filesystemPath}"></label>
            </div>          
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Save</button>
        </form>
```

`required` attribute on input field will shut up when provided with whitespace but there will be error message from Spring's validation. Clearing this field and returning it to user will make things more consistent than showing mixed signals such as:
[image: html5 and spring showing their errors]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `BeanPropertyBindingResult` object that provides the fields having the errors. Then make a model with this results,

```
@PostMapping( "/add" )
public String addExecute( @Valid @ModelAttribute WatchedDirectory watchedDirectory, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirect, Model model )
{
    if( result.hasErrors() )
    {
        BeanPropertyBindingResult result2 = new BeanPropertyBindingResult( watchedDirectory, theBindingResult.getObjectName() );
        for( ObjectError error : theBindingResult.getGlobalErrors() )
        {
            result2.addError( error );
        }
        for( FieldError error : theBindingResult.getFieldErrors() )
        {
            result2.addError( new FieldError( error.getObjectName(), error.getField(), null, error.isBindingFailure(), error.getCodes(), error.getArguments(), error.getDefaultMessage() ) );
        }

        model.addAllAttributes( result2.getModel() );
        return "mng-dir-add";
    }
    watchedDirectory = fs.persistDirectory( watchedDirectory );
    redirect.addFlashAttribute( "added", watchedDirectory );
    return "redirect:/list";
}
```

Comment: Neat, it works! So much better solution than https://stackoverflow.com/a/16851876/4618338 Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

According to [***Validation by Using Spring’s Validator Interface***](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validator) from the *Spring Framework Documentation*:

> The `Validator` interface works by using an `Errors` object so that,
>   while validating, validators can report validation failures to the
>   `Errors` object.
>
> `validate(Object, org.springframework.validation.Errors)`: Validates
>   the given object and, in case of validation errors, registers those
>   with the given `Errors` object.

And the [*`Errors`*](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) interface doesn't provide any API for deregistering binding errors.

So, it seems there is no `Spring` provided way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but by no means I want to deregister error - on contrary - I want to keep them. Unfortunately while you *can* modify correct parameters of `@Valid` object you *can't* do this to parameters that failed validation phase, Spring simply reverts every change made to them and pushes it back to view.